# Is there a filesystem that is "friendly" to both windows and Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for sharing and using data between Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot](https://superuser.com/questions/132754/suggestions-for-sharing-and-using-data-between-ubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot)

I'm planning to install Ubuntu 10.04 with Windows 7. (I'm new to Linux, have to use at work so I'm planning to install it at home to learn more)

I plan to use a partition to my Windows system files (C:), another for my personal files that already exists (D:) and a new one for Linux.

I want to have a partition for my personal files that works across these systems - so, if I boot with Windows or Linux, there are the same "Videos", "Pictures", "Projects" folders.

Is it possible? Is there a hd filesystem capable of having writes from both systems without *too much risk* of corrupting or something? (Can't be FAT32, I need to store >4gb files). I've read some [horror stories](https://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted) of corruption, and would like to know from a other people's experiences some POV about all the risks involved in such scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend NTFS, Linux read/write support is stable enough for NTFS in my opinion for home use.

Comment: NTFS support is still fairly new (4-5 years) to Linux. I am still a little fearful of something getting corrupted. That is mainly because I had it bite me early on.

Comment: Ya, the 4GB limit of fat32 might be a problem for videos though.

Comment: When it first came out. I transferred a bunch of files, and it locked on me and corrupted a bunch of important files. So I never trust it anymore. By now most of the bugs have been worked out, so it is probably fine, I am still scared of it though.

Comment: I use NTFS on Linux every day - reading and writing, HDs and pendrives, even created and resized NTFS partitions. Works perfectly.

Comment: If you are doing intense I/O, then NTFS-3G has has significant overhead. But there is really no other choice, unless you want to try one of the ext plugins for Windows.

Comment: I had transfer speed issues with NTFS in linux.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you don't want to install anything extra in Windows, you have two choices: FAT32 and NTFS. You need large files, so NTFS it is.

If you are willing to install something in Windows, there are several ways to mount an EXT2 or EXT3 filesystem in Windows.
http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2007/03/mount-ext2-or-ext3-partition-in-windows.html

Comment: Do you have experience in mounting EXT filesystem on windows?

Comment: @Somebody I have used it a little bit, but that was when I still had a Win32 machine floating around. As far as I can remember, it was well integrated into Explorer and fairly stable.

Answer (score 1):

Fat32 is easily read by both operating systems.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I need to store >4gb files.

Comment: Do you know if it's more reliable, and it would avoid problems like this one? -> http://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted Being more reliable, I could store >4gb elsewhere.