# Using USB drive in Windows and Linux properly

Tags: linux, windows, usb, filesystems

What is the proper way of using a USB hard drive or stick between Linux and Windows? (I'm using Linux Mint 14 and Windows XP on different machines) Should I set it up somehow so that all the files are shared and reused safely between Linux and Windows?

The question comes from the recent problem I had. I've created and edited a few folders through Linux and they are not working on Windows now (***folder* is not accessible. The file or directory is corrupt**). While I dealt with that problem, what would be the way of ensuring this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a filesystem that is "friendly" to both windows and Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/140744/is-there-a-filesystem-that-is-friendly-to-both-windows-and-linux) No idea what you did, but both FAT32 and NTFS should be fine (use the latter obviously if you have files bigger than 4GB each).

Comment: That question is not duplicate as it asks which filesystem to use. I ask what are the actions to ensure the smooth use of the drive, apart from filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've used the device sould be fine.  It is highly unlikely that Linux cannot handle the file system found on a "common" USB mass storage device.

But what probably went wrong (and often happens to me): the file system buffer has not been written back to disk.  Read/write access on mass storage devices is memory-buffered, which means before detaching the device you should make sure the buffer has been synced by the OS--either by `umount`-ing the device or by executing the `sync` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to keep windows/linux files apart you have 2 options to make things simple.

1. Make 2 completely different directories for the files of each, simply label one linux, the other windows.
2. Partition the drive as to have equal amounts of space on both sides, or more on whatever type of OS you are going to be using more/having more applications/needing more storage on. You could also format the linux partition in FAT32 and the windows in NTFS since although they both work with each other, FAT32 is suited more for linux where as NTFS is suited more for windows.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about shared use. Otherwise I'd just buy two drives...

Comment: While I dealt with that problem, what would be the way of ensuring this doesn't happen again?

You may want to edit your question to reflect that then.

Comment: "all the files are reused safely" means in both Linux and Windows

Comment: edited to clarify